# Need help about localhost. Why can't I connect to localhost via any browser?

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost

I can't connect to `localhost` via any browser, despite having started Apache and MySQL in XAMPP Control Panel.

For example, when I try to connect it via Opera, the Opera browser shows me the error message:
"This webpage is not available. Opera's connection attempt to localhost was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured."

And so does the other browsers like Chrome. The Chrome browser shows me the following error message:

"This webpage is not available. ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

What I am doing wrong? Please help.

Comment: Do you have the project files inside the xampp > htdocs folder?

Comment: It's **not** a browser issue. It's a problem of your config on XAMPP.

Comment: @Captain Red : I haven't made project file inside it.

Comment: @Vinicius Fagundes : Could you tell me about the steps of fixing this problem?

Comment: When you start Apache in XAMPP (not necessarily MySQL for now) and type localhost in the address bar, you should have a XAMPP homepage. If you do not get till this point, you have not set up XAMPP correctly. Also, if you have skype open, it could cause a problem too because both localhost and skype uses the same port no. 80 so try completely quitting skype (although you have option in skype to use another port)

Answer (score 1):

The Chrome error `ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED` means that the machine (yours) has actively refused Chrome's connection attempt at the port 80 which is what HTTP servers use by default.

To fix that, you need to go to Apache's settings at the `httpd.conf` file and add a port listener:

```
# Listen to port
Listen *:80
```

After that, simply restart Apache and try connecting to `localhost` again.